# Bird feeder - hydrostatic equilibium

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I was attempting a project to make a water feeder for birds during drought but failed at step one - getting the feeder to work.

There is a setup [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151452/how-do-simple-bird-waterers-work) which I should have checked first.

My setup looks like this:

[image]

I currently have no hole in the side of Reservoir but wanted to know if I can salvage the setup by putting a hole in at the level I want the water level in the tray to be at.

Note there is a lid to the reservoir which is shut tight without it shut the water just overflows.

I think the hole (if it will work this way - without the reservoir in the tray) should go between y and z  - or above the water outlet (i.e. above z?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the lid on and shut it airtight. If you put a hole in at any level, air will flow in and water will flow out.

The level of the spigot determines the water level if there is no air hole. Water can only flow out if air flows in. With no air hole, water can only flow in if the water level drops below the level of the spigot.

Comment: Doesn't the air hole determine the water level? And the air hole must be above the water hole?

Comment: I have several water bowls in my yard. The most popular two are the shallowest and the one nearest cover.